# How to Get The List of Instances' Properties from Instance List in C#

Tags: c#

Imagine I have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `List<Person>` that contains 3 people, say

```
{ 1, "john", "yellowstone" }
{ 2, "jack", "redstone" }
{ 3, "jennifer", "greenstone" }
```

How can I drain the list's all element's `PersonId` into a `List<int>`, which should then contains elements `{ 1, 2, 3 }` ? I know the old-school solution, is there any shortcut for this operation in C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myList.Select(p => p.PersonId)` will give you a list containing just the `PersonId` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Loocid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987253/loocid)  points out that
`myList.Select(p => p.PersonId)` will give you a list containing just the PersonId properties.

Comment: Technically, `myList.Select(p => p.PersonId)` produces `IEnumerable<int>`, not list; if you insist on `List<int>`, add `.ToList()`: `var myList = `myList.Select(p => p.PersonId).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

The smarter solution is using Linq.

For example in your case:

```
List<int> personIds = people.Select(person => person.PersonId).ToList();
```

This approach is more concise and follows the LINQ-style query syntax, making your code more readable and maintainable.